# WPF Window with Style=None cover taskbar when Maximised after app initialization

Tags: wpf, layout, resize

I want to achieve the same effect as Windows Media Player or Browser based Flash players which take up the ENTIRE (not even the taskbar is visible) real estate when maximized.

This works fine if the `WindowState` is set to `Maximized` and the `WindowStyle` is set to `None` in XAML so the app is started in that state. Problem is I want to start the app in a bordered window and when the user chooses, maximize as specified above. In the `StateChanged` handler I check for `Maximized` state and if this is the case I set the `WindowStyle` to `None`. This has the effect of maximizing the window but NOT covering the taskbar. The following code will make this work as I want but its a hack and I'd like to clean it up:

```
if (WindowState == WindowState.Maximized)
{
    m_videoWindow.Maximize();

    WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;

    //the following makes this work but I would like to clean it up
    Hide();
    Show();
}
```

**EDIT** [This](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/d3a88db7-28ce-49cb-bb79-57a982cf69ae) (from 2006 when still in CTP) mentions the problem and someone from MS states they hope to improve full screen support in the next version, have these improvements been made?

Comment: This issue is still alive and well with all the latest versions of WPF/.NET 4.0... -- I guess Microsoft wanted this bug to be backwards compatible...  your hide/show fix works great though...  I'm doing mine a little differently, calling Hide, setting the properties, then calling Show.

Comment: Well damn.  I noticed some of my controls aren't being resized properly, no idea why (either with my order, or with your order...);  Quick solution was to Maximize, call DoEvents(), set WindowStyle to None, then call Hide & Show. -- DoEvents is of course System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents() (Yes, I know that's insane, and probably worst practice, but it works...)

Answer (score 14):

This article explains it all: [Maximizing window (with WindowStyle=None) considering Taskbar](http://blogs.msdn.com/llobo/archive/2006/08/01/Maximizing-window-_2800_with-WindowStyle_3D00_None_2900_-considering-Taskbar.aspx).

Also worth checking out: [Custom Window Chrome in WPF](http://blogs.msdn.com/wpfsdk/archive/2008/09/08/custom-window-chrome-in-wpf.aspx).

**Edit**: Now new, is the WPF Shell Integration Library that allows complete restyle of the window chrome without the headaches of reimplementing move, resizing, etc.

**Edit 2015**: Shell Integration Library is now integrated in WPF and MS retired the code

Comment: Thanks Eduardo. I had read that but was hoping there was a solution which didn't require Win32. I'm sure there must be something, as the hack that I mention above works....

Comment: I guess there is not, because the behavior is by design, so you can have a window that takes all the desktop, like BabySmash.

Comment: Is it not strange though that when initially loading the window with WindowStyle = None and WindowState = Maximised the taskbar is obscured but when maximising the window after its loaded this is not the case?

Comment: @Simon: I do not see the behavior you are are describing. In my case always cover the taskbar

Comment: I see the issue.  Full screen works from XAML.  Remove it from XAML, and do it in code, and it doesn't cover the taskbar anymore... Using the latest .NET 4.0/Visual Studio 2010 Professional.

Comment: @EduardoMolteni, the last link you give has been retired.

Comment: @gregsdennis: Shell Integration Library is now integrated in WPF and they retired the code.

Comment: Very good option this one http://blogs.msdn.com/b/llobo/archive/2006/08/01/maximizing-window-_2800_with-windowstyle_3d00_none_2900_-considering-taskbar.aspx

Better than setting maxsize as with maxsize the window was still covering part of the taskbar.

Answer (score 4):

I found I could maximize to full screen (covering the taskbar) by setting the properties when creating the window (in xaml), but was not able to switch back and forth after creation. After some experimenting, I found the order the properties are set seems to matter:

```
public bool IsFullscreen
{
    get 
    {
        return WindowState == System.Windows.WindowState.Maximized
            && ResizeMode == System.Windows.ResizeMode.NoResize
            && WindowStyle== System.Windows.WindowStyle.None;
    }
    set
    {
        if ( value )
        {
            ResizeMode = System.Windows.ResizeMode.NoResize;
            WindowStyle = System.Windows.WindowStyle.None;
            WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Maximized;
        }
        else
        {
            ResizeMode = System.Windows.ResizeMode.CanResize;
            WindowStyle = System.Windows.WindowStyle.SingleBorderWindow;
            WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Normal;            
        }
    }
}
```

Note that **WindowState comes last** in the setter.

Comment: ok, so this should be the accepted answer, as what you said is the relevant part: `Note that WindowState comes last in the setter.`

Answer (score 2):

To get this to properly work in my WPF/.NET 4.0 application I am calling this function whenever I enter or exit full screen mode:

```
private static void RefreshWindowVisibility(Window window)
        {
            if (window.OriginalWindowState == WindowState.Maximized)
            {
                window.Hide();
                window.Show();
                window.BringIntoView();
            }
        }
```

There is a flicker associated with this method, but it seems the same flicker exists when going to full screen mode on Chrome. Internet Explorer seems to take a different approach.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is ok for you, but you can resize the window to have the same size than the working area (that is, in most cases, all the screen except the taskbar) and locate it at 0,0 (top-left corner):

```
Width = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width; 
Height = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height; 
Left = 0; 
Top = 0;
```

The exact definition for the WorkingArea property (from MSDN) is:

Gets the working area of the display. The working area is the desktop area of the display, excluding taskbars, docked windows, and docked tool bars.

Hope it helps

Comment: What if the taskbar is on top? Or you have multiple monitors?

Comment: Yeah, I had the same idea, but came to the same objection.  Pity it's not simple to query which monitor the application is on, and get the exact RECT for that monitor... there's probably some interop call to do it, but screw that...

Comment: @EduardoMolteni you could use bounds (`.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width`) instead of working area.