# can't use tabitems on fullscreen wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

so i have a problem where i can't use my tabitems on fullscreen but some times i can open the tabs by randomly click around the screen and also the form covers the taskbar

XAML for tabcontrol and window and controlls

```
    <<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:omini_dækberegner"
    xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
    xmlns:Obselete="clr-namespace:Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.Obselete;assembly=Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit" x:Class="Omini_Tires_And_rims.MainWindow"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="omini_dækberegner" Height="903.43" Width="1175.414" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" AllowsTransparency="True" WindowStyle="None" ResizeMode="NoResize" Loaded="Window_Loaded" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
<Window.Resources>   



       <Button x:Name="Maximize" Click="Maximize_Click" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent" Foreground="Transparent" IsTabStop="False" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="40" Width="39" Margin="0,18,67,0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" FontSize="18.667">
        <Image>
            <Image.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding WindowState, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}, Mode=FindAncestor}}" Value="Normal">
                            <Setter Property="Source" Value="img\maximize_window-.png"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding WindowState, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}, Mode=FindAncestor}}" Value="Maximized">
                            <Setter Property="Source" Value="img\restore-window-icon-61212.png"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Image.Style>
        </Image>
    </Button>

  <TabControl x:Name="tabControl" Margin="-2,70,0,-76" Background="#FF494949" BorderBrush="#FF494949" Foreground="#FF494949" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">

     <TabItem Header="Dækberegner"  Background="#FF303030" Foreground="#FFEAEAEA" BorderBrush="#FF303030" Margin="0,0,-21,0" FontSize="16" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">



  <TabItem BorderBrush="#FF303030" Background="#FF303030" Foreground="#FFEAEAEA" FontSize="16" Header="Betegnelser" Margin="22,0,-22,0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
            <Grid Margin="10,0,-10,42" Background="#FF494949">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ListView x:Name="betegnelser_list" Margin="206,47,187,150" Background="#FF303030" BorderBrush="#FF303030" Foreground="#FF00B408" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <ListView.View>
                        <GridView>
                            <GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">

                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black" />
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFEAEAEA                                                 " />
                                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                                </Style>
                            </GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Betegnelse"
                                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding betegnelse}"
                                Width="400"/>

                            <GridViewColumn Header="Betydning"
                                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding betydning}"
                                Width="400"/>

                        </GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
                </ListView>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
```

C# code

```
        private void Maximize_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.WindowState == System.Windows.WindowState.Normal)
        {
            this.WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Maximized;
        }
        else
        {
            this.WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Normal;
        }
    }
```

[video](https://youtu.be/KUujnXuwI3k)

Comment: I'm wondering why you are using: `RenderTransformOrigin`

Comment: not exactly sure why i had it since it only was on some of my controls i guess i had played around with some settings to see if i could get it to work probaly in fullscreen

Comment: Well I'd remove that for a start. I'd also suggest removing the fixed size for the window - set ResizeToContent to WidthAndHeight

Comment: that worked but now my form just goes behind the task bar and dont fully recover the whole screen

Comment: Can you add a screen shot?

Comment: updated with pictures but i see is only the 2 tabitems that goes under the taskbar and then i can't use any of the tabitems

Comment: Did you remove the Height= and Width= for the Window?

Comment: yes but not for the grids

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464908/wpf-window-with-style-none-cover-taskbar-when-maximised-after-app-initialization

Comment: i added a video and as you can see in the video when i go fullscreen i can use none of my tabitems when krydsmål or betegnelser tab is opned

Comment: figured it out the issue was the label was a little bit to close to the last 2 tab items so now i just need to figure out how to prevent it from go over my taskbar and go 100% fullscreen